# Outlook desktop app with Office 365, how to delay sending email without requiring Outlook to remain open?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

Office 365 is a cloud service.

From outlook.office.com , I can compose a message , click the arrow next to the Send , and Schedule Send for later tonight after I've closed my laptop.

From the Outlook desktop application, connected to only the same service, if I compose the message , click into Options->Delay Delivery , I can choose Do Not Deliver Before date/time .

The desktop app appears to only send while Outlook remains open.  If I shut down my laptop, the message will not be sent.  If I exit Outlook, it warns me that there are messages waiting to be sent.

How do I make the desktop application of Outlook send at the designated time despite Outlook not being open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To guarantee a delayed send from Outlook desktop app when using Office 365 despite the app being closed or the computer shut down :

1. In Outlook , click File->Account Settings->double click username@example.com ->Uncheck "Use Cached Exchange Mode"
2. Restart Outlook
3. Write a new message.  Options->Delay Sending
4. When you Send this message , it immediately goes to the server , and the server will send it at the appropriate time.

The default for Office 365 is to use Cached.  Cached is faster, searches work better/properly, and it won't hassle you to log in several times per week.

To do a similar thing from Outlook on the Web :

A.  Open OWA at outlook.office.com

B.  Write the message , click the little arrow by Send and choose "Schedule Send".

C.  Click Custom Time and set the date / time as desired.  Click Send.

D.  The server will send it at the appropriate time.

Comment: Good sharing!!!